# What is the correct way to configure Traefik to work with the Rancher backend?

Tags: rancher, traefik

I've been trying to get Traefik to work with the Rancher backend by following the documentation but when looking at the web interface I always get a Rancher tab that is completely blank.

Starting the container with the following parameters gives me the blank page:

```
--web.address=0.0.0.0:8080
--rancher 
--rancher.domain=subdomain.example.co.uk 
--rancher.endpoint=https://rancher.example.co.uk/v1
--rancher.accesskey=EXAMPLEKEY
--rancher.secretkey=EXAMPLESECRETKEY
--logLevel=DEBUG
```

Likewise the equivalent config file gives the same result:

```
logLegel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[web]
address = ":8080"

[rancher]
domain = "subdomain.example.co.uk"
  [rancher.api]
  endpoint = "https://rancher.example.co.uk/v1"
  accessKey = "EXAMPLEKEY"
  secretKey = "EXAMPLESECRETKEY"
```

The logs contain the following message for each of the services it finds:

```
07/12/2017 15:21:33DEBU[2017-12-07T15:21:33Z] Filtering service service/stack-name without traefik.port label
```

[Screenshot of blank Rancher tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNwQO.png)

I've tried this on version 1.4, 1.5-rc1 and 1.5-rc2.

The instructions for the Rancher backend don't mention having to set the `traefik.port` label and I don't want to set it. I just want to use port 80 on all containers that expose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the Docker backend behaves in the way requested the Rancher backend does not. This is not documented as it is not how it should work. As such, the developers advised me to raise this as a bug. The bug report can be found below.

https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/2541

Answer (score 0):

It looks like traefik is connecting to Rancher fine. What kind of labels do you have set on the containers in Rancher? Reading your error it looks like the dockers in Rancher need these labels:

```
traefik.port=12345
```

Or add a mapped port on your dockers in Rancher.